# Why does this code sporadically hang on std::condition_variable::wait()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer, condition-variable, stdthread

I have implemented a quite standard single-consumer-multiple-producer pattern, in C++ with the addition that there is a limit on the number of tasks in the queue.

A Worker runs a message queue on a separate thread. Tasks are sent to the Worker from producers. If there are already `max_num_tasks_` in the queue, the producers must wait.

Compiles in VS2022 for windows x64 using toolset v143.

The following code hangs sporadically in `Worker::Send()` at the statement `cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return (mq.Size() < max_num_tasks_); });`. Anyone sees what I'm doing wrong?

Implementation of the Worker

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

class Worker {
public:
    ~Worker() {
        Send([this] {done = true; });
        thd.join();
    }

    Worker(size_t max_num_tasks) : max_num_tasks_(max_num_tasks), done(false), thd([this] {
        while (!done) {
            mq.PopFront()();
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
        })
    { }

    void Send(std::function<void()>&& m) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
            cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return (mq.Size() < max_num_tasks_); });
        }
        mq.PushBack(std::move(m));
    }
private:
    bool done;
    size_t max_num_tasks_;
    ThreadSafeQueue<std::function<void()>> mq;
    std::thread thd;
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
};
```

Implementation of the ThreadSafeQueue

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class ThreadSafeQueue {
public:
    void PushBack(T&& val) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
            q.push(std::move(val));
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void PushBack(const T& val) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
            q.push(val);
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    T PopFront() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [&] { return (!q.empty()); });
        T v = q.front();
        q.pop();
        return std::move(v);
    }

    bool Empty() const {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
        return q.empty();
    }

    size_t Size() const {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(q_mutex);
        return q.size();
    }
private:
    mutable std::mutex q_mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::queue<T> q;
};
```

Example of unit test that occasionally triggers the issue:

```
    TEST(WorkerTests, Compute_PI) {

        std::atomic<double> value;
        auto multiply_by_pi_over_four = [&value] {
            int n = 750;
            double v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                v += std::pow(-1, i) / (2 * i + 1);
            }
            value = value * v;
        };

        auto add_pi_over_four = [&value] {
            int n = 750;
            double v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                v += std::pow(-1, i) / (2 * i + 1);
            }
            value = value + v;
        };

        auto add_one = [&value] {
            value = value + 1;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3));
        };

        auto multiply_by_three = [&value] {
            value = value * 3;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            value = 0.0;
            {
                Worker worker(1);
                worker.Send(add_one);
                worker.Send(multiply_by_pi_over_four);
                worker.Send(multiply_by_three);
                worker.Send([]() {});
                worker.Send(add_pi_over_four);
            }
            EXPECT_GE(3.15, value.load());
            EXPECT_LE(3.14, value.load());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cv_`s synchronization is broken in the shown code.

```
cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return (mq.Size() < max_num_tasks_); });
```

The sequence of events performed by `wait()` is as follows:

1. The initial condition of the mutex is locked.
2. The `wait()` condition is checked.
3. If condition is false, the mutex is atomically unlocked and the condition variable is waited for.

Step 3 is an atomic, indivisible, operation, But step 2 ***is not indivisible with step 3***. It is a ***separate*** step.

So:

A. Step 2 happens. `return (mq.Size() < max_num_tasks_);` evaluates to false.

B. The Worker thread wakes up and quickly blows through everything in `mq`, signaling the condition variable each time, draining `mq` until it's empty.

C. The other thread wakes up from its slumber, moves to step 3, unlocks the mutex and waits for someone to signal the condition variable.

D. Nothing ever will signal the condition variable. The worker thread slept in a deep slumber, while the other execution thread honked the condition variable, repeatedly, as it quickly drained the queue.

E. The call to `wait()` now waits for the condition variable to be signaled, it never will.

Basically this `wait()` needs to use the ***same*** condition variable, and mutex, as the worker thread is using to lock its thread. This logic, of `wait()`ing for the queue to fall below its max. size, needs to be moved into the event queue and use the same mutex and condition variable.

Comment: I fail to understand this.

Comment: Try taking out a piece of paper, and drawing a line down the middle. The left half is the worker thread, the right half is the main thread. Write down, using a pen or pencil: A on the right side, B on the left side, then C, D, and E on the right side. Everything should now be crystal clear.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks for the very instructive answer. While I do (now) understand the A-E sequence, and what goes wrong, and that I need to lock on the same mutex, I don't understand why the wait() needs to use the same condition variable as the Worker thread.

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain." -- Scotty, "Star Trek III". If you wish to use one condition variable for signaling queue growth, and a different condition variable for signaling queue shrinkage, you can. As long as the right condition variable is used each time. With two condition variables it's easy to get confused which one should be used for which purpose, and in which situations. Everything will mostly work, until it doesn't, but only on Thursdays between the hours of 8am and 9am. With just one cv and one mutex, you can't get it wrong.

Comment: I suggested edit that should simply the answer, making it easier to understand.

Comment: The OP benefited from the description of the sequence of operations, in my answer.

Comment: Yet, it obfuscates what the problem is and how to fix it. It is fine to provide detailed answer, but it is bad without short quick summary. Say, in math, if people didn't write theorems' statement but only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

My second attempt as follows then:

```
class Worker {
public:
    ~Worker() {
        Send([this] {done = true; });
        thd.join();
    }

    Worker(size_t max_num_tasks) : max_num_tasks_(max_num_tasks), done(false), thd([this] {
        while (!done) {
            std::function<void()> f;
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
                cv_.wait(lock, [&] { return (!mq.empty()); });
                f = mq.front();
                mq.pop();
            }
            f();
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
        })
    { }

    void Send(std::function<void()>&& m) {
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_);
                cv_.wait(lock, [&] {return (mq.size() < max_num_tasks_); });
                mq.push(std::move(m));
            }
            cv_.notify_all();
        }
    }
private:
    bool done;
    size_t max_num_tasks_;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> mq;
    std::thread thd;
    std::mutex m_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
};
```

However it appears that from a performance viewpoint it would be beneficial to use two cv's to avoid the unnecessary wakeups of all consumer threads in Send(). But maybe this is negligible in the grand scheme of things ...

Comment: If anything, the current problem is that you execute the sent function while the mutex is locked. This is far from desired.

Comment: @ALX23z, What do you mean, "...execute the sent function while the mutex is locked?" Do you mean to say that the `Send` function should not lock `_m`? Locking `_m` is exactly what was necessary to fix the bug.

Comment: @SolomonSlow he needs to extract the `std::function`, unlock mutex, notify the cv, and only then invoke it. Invoking it while the mutex is locked is ridiculous.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes. Edited the code now. Still, there is potential for a gridlock as both  wait statements may occur simultaneously.

Comment: @ALX23z, D'oh! I totally missed that you were talking about the call to the function object from the queue. You are absolutely right. The worker should unlock the mutex before calling that.

Comment: Is this an answer? Or an update to your question?